# how to change the syntax of this sql query to 92's explicit join systax

Tags: sql

How can i rewrite the below query in SQL '92's Explicit join syntax using only inner or outre joins

```
SELECT  e.emp_id ,
( SELECT    AVG(salary)
  FROM      #salary d
  WHERE     d.emp_id = e.emp_id )
FROM    #emp e
```

Comment: sorry forgot to mention, can't use group by

Comment: You can't have an average without grouping -- unless you're trying to show the same average salary for all employees.

Comment: but this query works fine..i just wanted to rewrite using the 92 syntax. can the same be implemented using simple joins?

Comment: `group by` was *made* for jobs like this.  That you "can't use" it makes no sense, and makes this look considerably less like a real question.

Comment: What part of your query is not "92 syntax"? You are not using the "implicit join notation". You are kind of not doing a join but a correlated sub query and that is the way to do it if you don't want to use `group by`.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not even sure why you need the outer select;  The employee id is present in both tables, you don't need a join at all:

```
SELECT salary.emp_id, AVG(salary.salary)
FROM salary
GROUP BY salary.emp_id
```

Well, maybe some employees aren't salaried, and you just want a NULL (is `AVG()` strict on your DBMS?)

```
SELECT e.emp_id, AVG(d.salary)
FROM employee e
LEFT OUTER JOIN salary d ON e.emp_id = d.emp_id
GROUP BY e.emp_id
```

Comment: Why are you qualifying the columns in your first query?

Comment: habit.  also I have to type 15 characters.

Comment: trying to achieve this without using group by like in original query but with 92s syntax. Is that possible?

Comment: You are taking an aggregate;  there is a window operation happening whether you use `GROUP BY` or a subselect in the select list;  why do you think you want a subselect?

Comment: need to implement group by without using "group by"

Comment: @Tushar: ...wait, what?  You can do random subselects, but not `group by`?  What DB is this that's so ass-backward?

Answer (score 0):

Good point byTokenMacGuy about not needing the #emp table. However, let's say that you only want to query those records in #salary that are also in #emp. In that case, you'll need to move your WHERE clause to the ON clause of a join, and add a GROUP BY clause:

```
SELECT  e.emp_id, AVG(d.salary)
FROM      #salary d
INNER JOIN #emp e  ON d.emp_id = e.emp_id 
GROUP BY e.emp_id
```

Comment: i need the query without using the group by..like in original one. just want different syntax